# How to pan inside diagram of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, uipangesturerecognizer

Actually, i draw a diagrams like triangle, rectangle, pentagon in MyView which subclass of UIView. When i touch any point on MyView (ether that point inside diagram or not), MyView is moved. I would like to touch inside point of diagram then it has to be moved. I am using pan gesture recognizer on MyView.Please suggest to me.

My Code is:

In `ViewController.m`,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyView *myView = [[MyView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];
    [pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
    [myView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [pinchGesture release];
}

- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}
```

In `MyView.m`,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    context =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    // And draw with a blue fill color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50.0, 10.0);  
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 5.0, 70.0);  
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150.0, 55.0); 
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I don't understand what your app is currently doing and how you'd like it to change. Are you saying that your pan gesture recognizer is moving the whole MyView and you'd rather just move individual "diagrams" (i.e. your various types of polygons) instead? What type of objects are these polygons? How did you create them? If you clarify your question and post your current code, perhaps we can help.

Comment: Actually i draw diagram only one on MyView and I applied pan gesture recognizer on MyView.

Comment: So, your pan gesture recognizer is working? If it's working, but not the way you want, describe how you want it to change. If your gesture recognizer is not working, tell us what you've tried so far. I _really_ encourage you to be far more explicit (both describe it and show us code) about (a) what you've tried; (b) what's not working. I have no clue as to what your question is. You really must clarify, explain your question in far greater detail. Please edit and expand your original question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have code here that does a pinch gesture and you want to additionally do a pan gesture? If so, I would suggest you create the pan gesture in viewDidLoad:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(movePiece:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
```

Then add an ivar to your MyView class:

```
CGPoint _originalCenter;
```

And, finally, have the method to move your view:

```
- (void)movePiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        _originalCenter = [gestureRecognizer view].center;
    }
    else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];

        [gestureRecognizer view].center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x + translation.x, _originalCenter.y + translation.y);
    }
}
```

As an aside, a few observations regarding your code:

1. You're setting your pinch gesture's delegate, but that's not necessary. That's accomplished by the `initWithTarget` method.
2. In your `drawRect` method, I think you want to call `CGContextClosePath` before you call `CGContextDrawPath`.

Regardless, I hope I answered the question by showing you an example of how you could use a pan gesture to move your subview. (You said "I am using pan gesture..." but I assumed you meant "I would like to use pan gesture...".) If I misunderstood your question, then please clarify and rephrase the question and we can take another crack at answering it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But  i would like to touch a point in area of diagram then myView has to be moved. I have got another way. Thank you for spending your valuable time for me.